# What is a good replacement/extension of syslog module in AWS Fargate?

Tags: log-messages

I usually disable dblog and enable syslog in production. Now I'm trying to do something similar in AWS Fargate in order to redirect Drupal log to CloudWatch.

syslog is easy to setup on a server, but not so much in a container. I found a module called [log_stdout](https://www.drupal.org/project/log_stdout) that aims to redirect Drupal log messages to stdout and stderr, but it appears to require dblog. Is there any other way to redirect Drupal logs to stdout or a log file so it could be injected by something like CloudWatch?